# How to create an Azure.AsyncPageable for mocking?

Tags: c#, azure, asynchronous, mocking, paging

I would like to mock a C# method that returns an **Azure.AsyncPageable**.

This class has only protected constructors, so I cannot instantiate it directly. Is there any way to create an instance of this class from some other collection, such as an **IAsyncEnumerable** or just a **List**?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can create `Page` objects `using Page<T>.FromValues`.
Then, create a `AsyncPageable<T>` using `AsyncPageable<T>.FromPages`.

Example:

```cs
        var page = Page<TableEntity>.FromValues(new List<TableEntity>
        {
            new TableEntity("1a", "2a"),
            new TableEntity("1", "2b")
        }, continuationToken: null, new Mock<Response>().Object);
        var pages = AsyncPageable<TableEntity>.FromPages(new[] { page });
```